# Custom adapter rebinds data to listview during scrolling

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a custom adapter that binds data (title, date, image) to a listview. Everything works fine, but when I scroll over my listview, it seems that the adapter re-binds its data to the listview. It does not populate or duplicate data but it writes over the same data position.
Something like that, especially when I present images it is very annoying because the listview scrolling is not smooth.
So, how I can stop the adapter to re-bind data on a listview?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> So, how I can stop the adapter to re-bind data on a listview?

Break all your users' fingers so they cannot scroll the `ListView`.

Or, do a more efficient job in your `bindView()` method, or whatever else you are using for binding (e.g., `ViewBinder`). For example, maintain a cache (via `SoftReferences` or something) of bitmaps so you do not have to re-load them from disk.

Comment: public View bindData(View view, int position) {
 if (data.get(position) == null) {
  return view;
 }
        Video item = data.get(position);
            
        aq = new AQuery(view);
        aq.id(R.id.title).text(item.getTitle());
        aq.id(R.id.date).text(item.getDate()); 
        aq.id(R.id.thumb).image(item.getImage(),false,true,100,R.drawable.icon);
        return view;
}

Comment: Above is the code that sets values to two textviews and one imageview. I use the Android Query library for this. This code runs each time I scroll the listview..

Comment: @Maverick: Of course it runs each time you scroll the `ListView`. That is the point behind `AdapterView`. Use Traceview to see specifically where things are slow in that code, and fix them to make them run faster.